# Fullcalendar refetch sources

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using fullcalendar with salesforce, and try to refetch sources in calendar that comes from controller. 
Form contains select option, so on change it must refresh calendar with values (recources and events).
So I went so far and have no results:

```
<apex:page controller="IBConferenceExtension" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.BootstrapMinCss4)}"/> 
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="{!$Resource.fullCalendarMinCSS}" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="{!$Resource.fullCalendarPrintMinCSS}" rel="stylesheet" media="print" />
<link href="{!$Resource.fullCalendarSchedulerMinCSS}" rel="stylesheet" />
<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.fullCalendarMomentMinJS}"/>
<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.fullCalendarJQueryMinJs}"/>  
<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.fullCalendarMinJS}"/>
<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.fullCalendarSchedulerMinJS}"/>    
</head>
<script>
    $ = jQuery.noConflict();
$(document).ready(function() {
    refreshCalendar();                 
});  
function refreshCalendar() { 
    <!--$('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeResource');-->             
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        schedulerLicenseKey: 'GPL-My-Project-Is-Open-Source',
        themeSystem: 'bootstrap4',
        now: '2019-02-22',
        defaultView: 'timelineDay',
        editable: true,
        eventDurationEditable: false,
        aspectRatio: 1.8,
        slotDuration: '01:00:00',
        minTime: '08:00:00',
        maxTime: '18:00:00',
        slotLabelFormat: 'HH:mm',
        height: 'auto',
        eventStartEditable: true,
        dragOpacity: 0.5,
        businessHours: {
            dow: [1,2,3,4,5],
            start: '08:00:00',
            end: '18:00:00',
        },
        eventConstraint: 'businessHours',
        header: {
            left: '',
            center: '', 
            right: ''                  
        },         
        resourceColumns: [
            {
                labelText: 'Accounts',
                field: 'title',
                width: '20%'
            },
            {
                labelText: 'Room #',
                field: 'room',
                width: '5%'
            }
        ],       
        resourceOrder: 'title',                    
        resources:[                
            <apex:repeat value="{!CorporateSets}" var="c">
                {
                    id: '{!c.id}',
                    title: '{!c.Corporate__r.Name}',
                    room: '{!c.Room_Name__c}',
                    businessHours: {start: '{!c.Start__c}', end: '{!c.End__c}'}
                },
            </apex:repeat>
        ],

        eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
            alert(event.title + " was dropped on " + event.start.format('HH:mm'));            
            if (!confirm("Are you sure about this change?")) {
                revertFunc();
            }
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);           
        }             
    });
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchResources');       
}        
</script>  
<style>
#legend { float:right;}
#legend ul {margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none;}
#legend ul li {margin:0;padding:5px;float:left;}
#legend ul li span {display:block; height:16px; width:16px; margin-right:4px; float:left; border-radius:4px;}
#calendar {margin-top:20px;}
#calendar a:hover {color:#fff !important;}

.footer {flex-shrink: 0; padding: 20px;}
.ev{border-radius:0.25rem;}    
.event-equity {background: red;border-color: red;}
.event-fi {background: orange;border-color: orange;}
.event-both {background: blue;border-color: blue;}
.event-lunch {background:#ff9f89;border-color:#ff9f89;}
.event-bh {background:#d7d7d7;border-color:#d7d7d7;}    
</style>  
<apex:form >
<apex:actionFunction reRender="cal" name="refresh"/>
   <div class="card bg-white mb-3 shadow">
    <div class="card-body">
        <ul class="pagination justify-content-left">
            <div class="form-group required">
                <label class='control-label'>Select conference</label>
                <apex:selectList value="{!selectedResult}" styleClass="form-control custom-select" size="1" id="Result" required="true">                        
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!Conference}"/>
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="cal" status="ajaxStatus" oncomplete="refreshCalendar();"/>  
                </apex:selectList>
            </div>
        </ul>
        <div id="legend">
            <ul>
                <li><span class="event-equity"></span>Equity</li>
                <li><span class="event-fi"></span>FI</li>
                <li><span class="event-both"></span>Both Equity And Fixed Income</li>                                       
                <li><span class="event-lunch"></span>Lunch</li>
                <li><span class="event-bh"></span>Not available</li>
            </ul>
            <div style="clear:both;"><!--fix floats--></div>
        </div>
        <apex:outputPanel id="cal">
            <div id="calendar"></div>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </div>
</div>
<footer class="text-muted text-center text-small footer">
    <hr class="mb-4"/>
    <p class="mb-1">© 2019 BCS Prime Brokerage</p>
</footer>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

VF Controller:

```
public class IBConferenceExtension {
    public String selectedResult {get;set;} 
    public String ConfDate {get;set;}

    public List<SelectOption> getConference(){
        List<SelectOption> conf = new List<SelectOption>();
        List<IB_Event__c> ibevent = [Select Id, Name From IB_Event__c];
        for(IB_Event__c iv : ibevent){
            conf.add(new SelectOption(iv.id, iv.Name));
        }
        return conf;
    }

    public IBConferenceExtension(){
        selectedResult = 'a0I1q000000WnbtEAC';     
    }

    public List<Corporate_set__c> getCorporateSets() {
        system.debug('selectedResult='+selectedResult);
        List<Corporate_set__c> cs = [Select Id, Corporate__r.Name, IB_Event__c, Room_Name__c, Start__c, End__c From Corporate_set__c where IB_Event__c =: selectedResult]; 
        system.debug('cs='+cs);
        return cs;    
    }

}
```

could anybody help?

Comment: What do you mean "no results"? Errors? Messages? Can you please be more descriptive?

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox ! No errors, but data in recources is not refreshed. So when onchenge event appear, getCorporateSets return null, but in recource object is still store them. Maybe I need to refresh apex repeat? But how to do this without wraping apex:repeat in outputpanel?

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox ! No errors, but data in recources is not refreshed. So when onchenge event appear, getCorporateSets return null, but in recource object is still store them. Maybe I need to refresh apex repeat? But how to do this without wraping apex:repeat in outputpanel?